# Añadir variable en la ruta de una imagen con Flutter

Tags: flutter

Buenas estoy intentando añadir una variable a la ruta de una imagen, pero no lo consigo intento `items['iconoPanel']` pero me da error todo el rato y si intento declararla antes para luego hacer por ejemplo `$foto` no me deja y me da error.

```
for (var items in tipos)
Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.network(
            'http://url/aqui-la-variable',
            width: 60.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
          Text(items['name'] .toUpperCase(), style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 9.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800
              ),)
         ],
       ),
     )
    ],
),
```

Comment: Que estás intentando hacer?

Comment: Estoy realizando un `for` para mostrar los servicios que tiene ese local, eso lo hago bien. Pero quiero añadirle la variable de el icono a la ruta pero sin éxito. Por ciento muy buenas @JonathanPerez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías intentar es lo siguiente:

```
  for (var items in tipos)
Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.network(
            'http://url/${items['iconoPanel']}',
            width: 60.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
          Text(items['name'] .toUpperCase(), style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 9.0,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800
              ),)
         ],
       ),
     )
    ],
),
```

Comment: Enserio?? te juro que lo probe pero sin éxito. Lo haria mal supongo. Muchas gracias!

Comment: En tal caso, puedes editar tu pregunta y poner el error que te sale

Comment: Esque el error que sale todo el rato es que espera "," no dice mucho más

Comment: el nombre del item si te lo muestra?

Comment: Si, sin problema. Eso me funcionaba bien

Comment: Has intentado hacer un for clásico? for(var x = 0; x < tipos.length; x++)

Comment: No lo intente, pero en esta ocasión la verdad que me entiendo bien con este tipo de `for` me parece bastante sencillo y facil de recordar como funciona

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137525/discussion-between-jonathan-perez-and-miguel).